# Is there any way to create my own css for an existing page?

Tags: css, customization

As a beginning IT'er, i want to create my own CSS file to use on an existing site, so it becomes more readable.

Is this possible at all? Do I need certain extentions on it? Is it browser-specific?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, it is possible. Actually you can create your own extension but I would recommend you to use Stylebot (for Chrome). Go to the Chrome's Web Store and [download](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/stylebot/oiaejidbmkiecgbjeifoejpgmdaleoha?hl=en) the extension. It is completely free.

Once you added your CSS for a certain web site the extension will save that CSS and use whenever you enter this web site again.

Comment: I'll try this, and approve your answer as soon as it works. Thanks a lot in advance!